# if coulmn of mysql is empty you get value from other table with same name of coulmn in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to get values from 'tournament_week' table of mysql but if one of its coulmn ''is null then get value from another table 'tournament' which have that same coulmn name. please guide me in codeigniter

MY MODEL

```
 $this->db->select(if'w.*, t.name tournament_name');
                    $this->db->from('tournament_week w');
                    $this->db->join('tournament t', 'w.tournament_id = t.id');
                    $this->db->where('w.tournament_id=', $tid);
                    $this->db->where('w.show_week', 1);
                    $this->db->order_by("w.week_no", "ASC");

             $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

        return $query;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column name is `name`

```
 $this->db->select('coalesce(w.name, t.name) as tournament_name, w.tournament_id,<all other tournament_week fields>');
```

Answer (score 1):

COALESCE function should work.
Try following.

```
    $this->db->select('COALESCE(w.name, t.name) tournament_name);
                $this->db->from('tournament_week w');
                $this->db->join('tournament t', 'w.tournament_id = t.id');
                $this->db->where('w.tournament_id=', $tid);
                $this->db->where('w.show_week', 1);
                $this->db->order_by("w.week_no", "ASC");

         $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    return $query;
```